# How to model country specific product information?

Tags: product, price, multistore, store-view

I am struggeling to find a suitable modelling approach for the following situation.

Base requirements:

- One store for each country, each store having one main currency
- Each country store can support multiple languages
- Some languages are used in multiple stores (i.e. German is used in Germany and Switzerland)

Product management / modelling requirements:

- Products are stock managed
- Products should be shared over the multiple country stores. But they have to vary in the attributes "price in store currency" and "power plug type". The german store should offer the toaster with the german plug only for EUR 35, whereas the swiss shop should offer the "same" product with the swiss plug only for CHF 40.
- The plug selection should properly impact the stock inventory.
- Avoid redundancy: It should be possible to edit the language specific attributes only once and then share it over multiple stores.
- Avoid redundancy: It should be possible to edit shared attributes only once: i.e. images, weight.

I tried different approaches but I always ended up having a lot of redundant product data to maintain.

Any suggestions on how to model the scenario in a way that fulfills the requirements but does not lead to product redundancy?

-- UPDATE --

Since the requirements only seemed to be misleading, I'm adding a short descripion of the actual scenario:

- 3 shops, each with its own domain: One for the netherlands (*.nl), one for Switzerland (*.ch) and one for Germany (*.de).
- Switzerland supporting 3 languages (german, french, italian), all product listed in CHF (Swiss Franc)
- Germany supporting german only, all products listed in EUR
- Netherlands supporting dutch only, all products listed in EUR
- All shops sell the same about 300 products. They only differ in price, language specific description and in power plug type.

We are trying to find a solution that doesn't force us to duplicate those products 3 or more times.

Comment: This is like assigning a project :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is entirely native to Magento.

The ability to set store-level attribute values is fundamental to the way Magento works.

In your example, you would create 3x websites, one for each respective country. Then, you would add products as necessary, but within the scope of each product, define different values for each store view for the plug type. You don't need 3 products, just 1 product with the attribute appropriately set at the store scope.

Using store views for language translation is expensive in terms of resource usage. Instead, you could easily extend the core functionality of Magento to translate the text (during the magic `__toString()` method) based on url/geo county code/session etc.